# how to call webservice after close app in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework

I updated the location to my server as backgound process without open app in ionic 2 framework. I referred and tried many ways but could not achive (my desired goal). Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cordova pause event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html) to run the processes when the user switch the app or let's say run processes in background.

The pause event fires when the native platform puts the application into the background, typically when the user switches to a different application.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
function onPause() {
    // Handle the pause event
}
```